# FutureBuilder freeze when decoding json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this large json string that I would like to decode. My problem is FutureBuilder freeze while decoding the json string and the `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting` was not triggered while decoding. I'm expecting to show circular loading bar while it still parsing the json string. Below is the same script.

```
Future<LocationList> _location;

  Future<LocationList> getLocation() async {
    final result = json.decode(LocationJson);
    LocationList locList = LocationList.fromJson(result);
    return locList;
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    _location = getLocation();
    super.initState();
  }
```

My FutureBuilder:

```
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _location,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<locList> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             CircularProgressIndicator()
          ...................
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. I've fixed it using [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html). Also `_decodeLocation` must be a global method or a static method, not a closure or an instance method as for this [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16265#issuecomment-379000381)

Here is the code:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> _decodeLocation(String jsonString) {
  return json.decode(jsonString);
  }

  Future<LocationList> getLocation() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> result = await compute(_decodeLocation, LocationJson);

    LocationList locList = LocationList.fromJson(result);
    return locList;
  }
```